# Moving folders in Moss 2007

Tags: 2007, folder, libraries

Is it supported to move folders with its content between libraries in Moss 2007 while retaining metadata? I tested dragging and dropping the folder through Explorer View and got a message saying *Unable to read from the source file or source disk*, I even tested using **Content and Structure** but the **Move** option is greyed out! Any suggestions? However the folder doesn't lie directly under the root site collection, but a little bit deeper down in the hierarchy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here are two approaches I came across:

- Using Explorer list view: moving the folder in this approach is unavailable as source and destination sites didn't exist in the root site collection, nor in a subsite directly the root site collection, it's simply not supported by microsoft.
- Using Content and structure: obviously it's not possible to copy a folder with all of its contents/subfolders from one place to another, however i used this approach by creating a similar folder construct in the destination site and then move the documents one by one while retaining the documents metadata but not the folders as i had to create them myself.

Just in case someone else faces the same issue, here you have the answer.